# SharePoint Calculated Currency to Power Automate Flow formatting

Tags: power-automate

I am using a calculated column (currency) in a SharePoint list, and putting the value into an email using a Power Automate Flow. The value will always be a dollar amount.

When the value is passed through to Flow, it's converted to a string with a decimal point and several zero's added, so $5,416.52 (in SharePoint) becomes 5416.52000000000 in the Power Automate E-mail.

I have been able to use the below line to resolve my integer problem for non-currency fields.

formatNumber(int(outputs('')?['body/']), '0', 'en-us')

Now I'm trying to do the same thing as above but with Currency.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  I have multiple calculated currency fields in the SharePoint list that I need to copy over.  So an Expression would be the best route forward.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your assistance. You definitely pointed me in the right direction.  Here is what I did to successfully convert my calculated fields.

**SharePoint Calculated Column Configuration**

[image: SharePoint Calculated Column Setup]

**Flow Configuration**

[image: Flow Configurations]

```
float(variables('var_Travel_Total'))
```

**Final Output**

[image: Final Output]

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[Format number]** action to format SharePoint values in Power Automate

[image]

**Output**

[image]

### Updating this post for SharePoint Calculated Column

**1) SharePoint Columns**
a) Single line of text b) Calculated column, output as Single line of text

[image]

**2) Power Automate**

[image]

**Expressions used**

```
1) outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']?[0]?['ColSingleLine']

2) outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']?[0]?['calculatedSingleLine']

3) float(variables('varCalculatedSingleLine'))

4) float(variables('varColSingleLine'))
```

**Final Output**
[image]

Comment: I tried using the steps that you demostrated above but still received the trailing zero's.  For the Value on the "Initialize Variable" I selected the field that I'm trying to import from the SharePoint calculated column.

I have also tried to change the output of the calculated column to "Single Line of Text", Number or Currency and all fail.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let me test this out with values from SharePoint - will update the post accordingly

Comment: [Format Number] action expects a [Number] value, so did you convert the SP field's value by using float() as shown in my example?

Comment: You must be doing something differently when accessing SharePoint Fields. I've just tested with SPO fields, with a [Single line of text] and a [Calculated] column output as *Single line text*. In my flow I used variables to capture values from the item and then convert to float before formatting using  [Format Number]. I can post my solution, if you need it

Comment: Just posted my response with [calculated] column. Let me know if you still see any issues. Or post your Power Automate for further troubleshooting